# Hillshade with too big pixels

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, hillshade

I digitized some maps with isolines every 4m. I created a DEM and the Hillshade. But the hillshade has big pixels. I use ArcGIS 10.3.

[image]

Is there something to be look out for that I might have done wrong?

Comment: Which program you are using?

Comment: Sorry I did not mention that I use ArcGIS 10.3. The only controls has the Hillshade command (Spatial Analyst) is input-output Azimuth Altitude and Z factor. Nothing else. I dont know if I have to change any controls in Enviromental Settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hillshade tool inherits cell sizes from the raster layer it is based on. If you are able to recreate this DEM using a smaller cell size, the resulting hillshade should also have smaller cells.

Comment: Of course it was a matter of DEM. From my rush not even think about it. Thank you very much.